# SilverLight and iPhone

Tags: iphone

I need to embed an silverlight or flash component in an iphone native application.
Can anyone tell me the compatibility for both in an iphone application.

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not support flash on iPhones.  I have a hard time believing that they would support Silverlight.

Comment: So are you telling that currently they dont support both?

Comment: Currently they do not support both and most likely will not in the future.  Especially on the silverlight side.  With the iPad, we will see more of a push for this.

Answer (score 1):

No compatibility for either.

Comment: So what is the solution of building a flashy component like a 3D object which can be rotated and its parts be clicked to get a detail view on iphone.
eg. An automobile which can be rotated 360 degrees and each part be clicked to view the details.Like clicking on the tyres shows the diameter etc.

Comment: OpenGL (fast) or CoreAnimation (easy)

Answer (score 1):

Novell offers [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) which will allow .NET code to be cross-compiled for the iPhone. Silverlight compatibility is on the [roadmap](http://monotouch.net/Roadmap)

Comment: A prototype is on the roadmap.